# PgAdmin 4 does not launch

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I just installed PGAdmin 4 on my machine for the sake of upgrading when my PgAdmin 3 is working all fine.

Now, when I launch it, it sounds like it is infinitely stuck on start up screen. I came across many threads and many people have suggested manythings like

- Install latest version of Java
- Get latest version of PGAdmin(which I was already doing)
- Get latest version of postgres

I did all of these but nothing seems to be working.

Any idea on what else can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: We can ask the developers of pgadmin to return to the technology of pgAdminIII.

Comment: I think that ship has sailed... It's best to either write to the [mailing list](https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/) or [open an issue](https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin4) (requires a PostgreSQL community account). But the report should be a little more detailed than this one: At least the operating system and how the software was obtained and installed would be necessary.

Comment: Personally i would stick with pgAdmin3 or move to a third party tool. pgAdmin4 is a little flaky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am not sure if this applies to everyone who is facing similar issues. However, in my case it turned out that PGAdmin4 would not load if Fiddler is running on my system. Weird but true.